# Select no banco de dados, somente com jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, postgresql

Como eu faço um select no banco de dados utilizando somente utilizando um jQuery? Tenho dois combobox e quero usar o valor deles para fazer um select no meu banco de dados:

```
        $.getJSON('/MinhaDoenca/rest/hospital/get', function(data) {

            for ( var index in data) {

                $("#idHospital").append(
                        '<option value="'+data[index].nome+'">'
                                + data[index].nome + '</option>')
            }

        });

        $.getJSON('/MinhaDoenca/rest/especialidade/get', function(data) {

            for ( var index in data) {

                $("#idEspecialidade").append(
                        '<option value="'+data[index].descricao+'">'
                                + data[index].descricao + '</option>')
            }

        });
```

Gostaria de pegar esses dois valores e fazer uma consulta no meu banco de dados, mas utilizando somente jQuery e HTML, sem PHP. É possível? Alguém poderia me passar um exemplo? (meu banco de dados é PostegreSQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível, pois o jQuery é uma biblioteca desenvolvida em Javascrit puro como provavelmente você deve saber ou deveria, que é uma linguagem de programação de script interpretado pelo Browser(Navegador) no lado do cliente(client-side), onde ela não consegue executar comandos internos no lado do servidor(server-side).

Então dessa forma não dar para fazer comandos de select no seu banco de dados usando somente JQuery, porque também seria algo de total insegurança para o seu site. E ser isso fosse possível qualquer programador poderia acessar seu site pelo console do Browser é fazer select's, insert's, update's, delete's etc em seu banco de dados.

O que seria possível seria criar uma API Rest, Soap, RPC em uma liguagem de programação do lado do servidor, onde com jQuery você a consumiria, que pelo seu código provavelmente é o que você quer fazer.

Se você está querendo criar um Web Service onde o consumiria somente com jQuery você poderia usar o framework slimframework do PHP, caso seja PHP que você está usando, aqui é um exemplo bem simples do uso dele:

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/MinhaDoenca/rest/hospital/get', function() {

  //Seu código para acessar o banco de dados

});
$app->run();
```

Obs.: Mas isso até é possível ser você usar Node.js que é uma plataforma construída sobre o motor JavaScript do Google Chrome que roda no lado do servidor como PHP, Java, Python etc, que não vez a caso aqui.

Comment: Mesmo consumindo um Web Service?

Comment: Quando eu disse API eu me referir a isso API Rest, Soap etc, que são formas de ser desenvolver Web Service's.

Comment: Que também usando um Web Service não fugiria de uma liguagem  de programação server-side como o PHP.